# How to convert a string from one codepage to another?

Tags: python, codepages

I need to convert this string into something readable.

```
'Old_video/\udcc2\udce8\udce4\udce5\udcee\udcef\udcf0\udce8\udcea\udcee\udceb\udcfb'
```

It doesn't have the `.decode` method, only `.encode`.

The worst part is that I'm not sure what codepage this is exactly. Probably it's `"cp1251"`.

I'm on python 3, but answers for python 2 are also welcome. I don't quite get what exactly was changed.

Comment: In Python 3 you can only `.decode()` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Probably it's "cp1251".

Close...ish.

Since it's full of low surrogates we can tell that it was decoded using `errors='surrogateescape'`, so first we need to encode it using that.

```
>>> 'Old_video/\udcc2\udce8\udce4\udce5\udcee\udcef\udcf0\udce8\udcea\udcee\udceb\udcfb'.encode('latin-1', errors='surrogateescape')
b'Old_video/\xc2\xe8\xe4\xe5\xee\xef\xf0\xe8\xea\xee\xeb\xfb'
```

And now that we have that we can try to decode it properly.

```
>>> 'Old_video/\udcc2\udce8\udce4\udce5\udcee\udcef\udcf0\udce8\udcea\udcee\udceb\udcfb'.encode('latin-1', errors='surrogateescape').decode('cp1251')
'Old_video/Видеоприколы'
```

If that's what the filename is supposed to be then congratulations, you guessed right.

Answer (score 0):

> In Python 3 you can only .decode() bytes. – kichik Nov 8 '17 at 0:27

Correct. .decode will convert a list of bytes to a String.
So, if you have a String, you must first convert it into bytes with `.encode()`, and then `.decode()` the result of that operation

So, for instance, if you have some utf-8 text String and want to convert to codepage 1252 (used in Western Europe computers),

```
text = sourcetext.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
```

In general, it should be:

```
source_codepage = 'utf-8'    # or whatever the current format is
target_codepage = 'cp1252'   # or whatever format you like

newtext = sourcetext.encode(target_codepage).decode(source_codepage)
```

where source_codepage and target_codepage are two strings containing respectively the name of the original text encoding and the desired one.

A full list of the codepage strings available in Python can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings